# Xslt transformation for grouping fromatting

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

This is the XML I want to traverse, grouping the data by `<SUBJECT>`. I am already able to do that, but I need to apply a condition to check if a `<DocumentList>` node is there, and if it's not there, show "no data found". Also with this it is taking also data that I don't want, like the screenshot below:

```
<KnowledgeBase>
  <DocumentCount>8</DocumentCount>
  <CountOnly>false</CountOnly>
  <DocumentList>
    <Document Identifier="428B474B-C016-4726-9325-20BC8B754427">
      <SUBJECT>Bariatric Surgery Coding Guidelines</SUBJECT>
    </Document>
    <Document Identifier="261489E7-14E0-43CF-9909-6892A84D4BEA">
      <SUBJECT>Bariatric Surgery Coding Guidelines</SUBJECT>
    </Document>
    <Document Identifier="1C336836-A5BB-424F-8A43-9BDD52A5BE9D">
      <SUBJECT>Bariatric Surgery Coverage R2</SUBJECT>
    </Document>
    <Document Identifier="65E77B48-E88B-4AAF-B0A6-ED14BD028905">
      <SUBJECT>Billing and Coding: Bariatric Surgery Coverage</SUBJECT>
    </Document>
  </DocumentList>
</KnowledgeBaseAdvancedSearchResponse>
```

XSLT I tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="//KnowledgeBaseAdvancedSearchResponse/DocumentList/Document" use="SUBJECT" />

  <xsl:template match="//KnowledgeBaseAdvancedSearchResponse/DocumentList">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Document[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', SUBJECT)[1])]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="SUBJECT" /></h1>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT that I want similar to with grouping for same data:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="//KnowledgeBaseAdvancedSearchResponse/DocumentList">
        <xsl:for-each select="//DocumentList/Document">
          <h1><xsl:value-of select="SUBJECT" /></h1>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>No policy edits for the selected Payor/State.</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="//Errors">There were errors.</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Next time you post an XSLT question, please don't dump your *entire* XML and your *entire* XSLT here. Cut out everything that has nothing to do with the question you're asking. You can't expect people to read through hundreds of lines of unrelated code. I've done that for you this time, next time please do it yourself before you post.

Comment: thanks for your answer and for formatting , will keep in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to apply a condition to check if a `<DocumentList>` node is there, and if it's not there, show "no data found".

Use `<xsl:apply-templates>` and two different templates. One matches `<KnowledgeBaseAdvancedSearchResponse>` that has `<DocumentList>` (and `<Document>`), and the other matches all other cases.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="Document" use="SUBJECT" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="KnowledgeBaseAdvancedSearchResponse" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="KnowledgeBaseAdvancedSearchResponse[DocumentList/Document]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DocumentList/Document[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', SUBJECT))]" />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="KnowledgeBaseAdvancedSearchResponse">
    <h1>No Data Found</h1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="SUBJECT" /></h1>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i am quite a newbie can you help me more with details of what you are trying to say :)

Comment: @umangyadav I don't understand that comment. Have you looked at the code? Have you tried it?

Comment: i tried it always gives me no data found

Comment: Can you make changes to my code and show me what exactly you mean , i am not able to get what yo mean

Comment: It does not always give "no data found", see for yourself. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1be If it does that for you, you are using different XML or you have made changes to the XSLT. Look at the code. It's only a few lines. *Try to understand what it does*, and then apply it to your situation. I'm not giving you "copy and paste"-code on purpose. You're supposed to learn something.

Comment: i got what you meant , thanks i am a new guy to it so took some time , thanks :)

Comment: will this reslve the screenshot problem too ?

Comment: @umangyadav That's good to hear! (Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.)

Comment: @umangyadav *"will this reslve the screenshot problem too?"* - If you use it the way it's intended, yes. The difference is the `<xsl:template match="/">`. Your code does not have that.

Comment: ok understood thanks will mark it as answered thanks

Comment: Let me just try it out and i will mark it as answer